# Magick++ C++ Input 16-bit Greyscale PNG

Tags: c++, c++11, magick++

I've got a series of PNG files that I know is in a 16-bit greyscale format. I haven't had a problem loading this up with Magick++ and getting access to the data in 8-bit format (this was done, primarily, because all the code was there and no change was necessary).

```
magick_image->write(0, 0, grey->GetWidth(), grey->GetHeight(), "R", Magick::CharPixel, grey->GetBeginData());
```

Please note that grey is in our own container for images, but the memory layout is just one block of pre-allocated memory.

I've now been told that we need to get access to the full 16-bit range, and I'm not too sure how to do this. I presume I wouldn't use Magick::CharPixel, but the others described in the documentation don't specify what bit size they actually are.

---

So, I need to be able to do the following things:

- Determine whether it is a 16-bit image in the first place
- Read out of the Magick::Image class into a block of memory that would map to place into a block of memory for a u_int16_t

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: From [color docs](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/Color.html), a quantum depth of 16 would be `Magick::ShortPixel`

Comment: Great! I've been looking for something like that, but I just couldn't find it. I'll test it as soon as I get a chance to. Now I just need to figure out a way to determine the quantum depth of a loaded image.

Comment: Better double check the documents, but `Magick::Image.depth` should give you 8, 16, or 32.

Comment: From what I see in the docs, it looks like that only allows you to specify the depth, not determine what it is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few ways to do this, but without seeing the definitions of `magick_image` & `grey`, this answer is based on a few assumptions.

To work with bare-bone `grey`, I would argue it could be defined as...

```cpp
struct MaybeGray {
    std::vector<u_int16_t> blob;
    size_t width;
    size_t height;
    MaybeGray(size_t w, size_t h) : blob(w * h) { width = w; height = h; };
    size_t getWidth() { return width; };
    size_t getHeight() { return height; };
    void * getBeginData() { return blob.data(); } // C11? Is this allowed?
};
```

Next, I'll create a 2x2 canvas image to satisfy `magick_image`.

```cpp
Magick::Image magick_image;
Magick::Geometry size(2, 2);
magick_image.size(size);
magick_image.read("XC:blue");
// Apply gray scale (Magick::Image.quantize may be better.)
magick_image.type(Magick::GrayscaleType);
```

> Determine whether it is a 16-bit image in the first place

`Magick::Image.depth` can be used to identify, and set depth value.

```cpp
const size_t DEPTH = 16;
if ( magick_image.depth() != DEPTH ) {
    magick_image.depth(DEPTH);
}
```

> Read out of the Magick::Image class into a block of memory that would map to place into a block of memory for a u_int16_t

What you're doing with `Magick::Image.write` is correct. However `Magick::CharPixel` would be for 8-bit, 256 colors, depth. For 16-bit, use `Magick::ShortPixel`.

```cpp
struct MaybeGray gray(2, 2);
magick_image.write(0, 0,
                   gray.getWidth(),
                   gray.getHeight(),
                   "R",
                   Magick::ShortPixel,
                   gray.getBeginData());
```

### How to test

A image canvas of `XC:red` should fill the blob with `0xFFFF`, and `XC:black` with `0x0000`. Use ImageMagick's `convert` & `identify` utilities to create the expected results.

```sh
# Create identical canvas
convert -size 2x2 xc:blue -colorspace gray -depth 16 blue.tiff
# Dump info
identify -verbose blue.tiff

  Image: blue.tiff
  Format: TIFF (Tagged Image File Format)
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 2x2+0+0
  Units: PixelsPerInch
  Type: Grayscale
  Base type: Grayscale
  Endianess: LSB
  Colorspace: Gray
  Depth: 16/14-bit
  Channel depth:
    gray: 14-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Gray:
      min: 4732 (0.0722057)
      max: 4732 (0.0722057)
      mean: 4732 (0.0722057)
      standard deviation: 0 (0)
      kurtosis: 0
      skewness: 0
  Colors: 1
  Histogram:
         4: ( 4732, 4732, 4732) #127C127C127C gray(7.22057%)
  # ... rest omitted
```

And the verbose info confirms that I have 16-bit gray image, and the histogram informs me that `MaybeGrey.blob` would be filled with 4 `0x127C`.

[image: 16-bit Greyscale PNG]

Which it is.

Comment: Sorry for the long wait. This does actually work now, for some reason the auto complete I'm using didn't think it had a return value... Thanks!